# Is a "wrist" a "toy" (muñeca)?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, definiciones, polisemia

Both wrist and toy are "muñeca" in Spanish. Is there a connection, or just a coincidence that they are both the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the word `muñeca` means not only "toy" or "wrist" but also defines a small mountain or a cloth rag. From [DRAE](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=mu%F1eca)

> Parte del cuerpo humano en donde se articula la mano con el antebrazo.
>
> Figura de mujer que sirve de juguete.
>
> Pieza pequeña de trapo que, atada con un hilo por las puntas, encierra algún ingrediente o una sustancia medicinal que no se debe mezclar con el líquido en que se cuece o empapa
>
> hito (mojón).

According to a handful of references I checked, the etymology of the word, to get to the meaning of "toy" in uncertain. This is just [one example:](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/mu%C3%B1eca)

> Etimología: incierta, indudablemente de origen no romance y emparentada con moño y muñón, quizás asimilable a la raíz del euskera muño, "monte".

Other references say that clearly the word comes from latin, and it designated the protuberance in the land, from there it came to designate the "protuberance" in the body (joining hand and arm). Possibly from there came to designate a protuberance on a piece of cloth or rag when you are using it to filter something and from there to designate the piece of cloth that would make a toy.

[Other references](http://etimologias.dechile.net/) say that the use of the word as a toy comes form around 1400, but they also mention the similarity of the word with "monnula", a latin word that mean "friend" or "companion".

Answer (score 5):

***Homonyms*** are words that are both spelled and pronounced the same, but have different meanings. "Muñeca" is a word that have multiple meanings in the Spanish language, just like the word "ball" in English.  In Spanish, you also have to be aware of ***homophones*** (word that sound the same, although spelled out differently).  For example, the words "hecho" and "echo" (the letter 'h' in Spanish is silent unless preceded by a 'c').  The former (hecho) means "create" or "make", whereas the latter (echo) means "deposit", "put in" or "throw in" as in putting trash in a thrash bin.

Answer (score 4):

**Muñeca del brazo ("wrist"):**

Como dijo Diego en su post, deriva de "muño" palabra previa a la influencia latina en la península ibérica y que se relaciona con "bulto", y de ahí con "colina". De hecho, el frecuente apellido vasco-ibérico "Muñoz", es un toponímico de *los que viven en la colina*. La terminación -eca probablemente deriva de un sufijo diminutivo.

Hasta hace poco *muñeca* era sólo el hueso saliente de la parte posterior de la unión entre la mano y el brazo (ese "montecito"), pero por sinécdoque pasó a referirse a la articulación completa, reemplazando al cultismo "carpo". La palabra "muñón" deriva de muñeca. La palabra "moño" (*nudo de pelo*) tiene origen itálico, no confundirla con el "moño" ibérico (*colina*).

**Muñeca juguete ("doll")**:

Su origen es incierto y de hecho para el etimólogo Joan Corominas (que es como un héroe de los que estudian la historia del español), es una simple derivación del mismo "bulto" ibérico anterior. Sería un truncamiento de "muñeca de trapo" (o sea, "bultito de trapo"), del que se quitó la parte "de trapo".

Pero hay una teoría distinta, atribuida a Roque Barcia, que dice que la muñeca *juguete* deriva de "mona", ya sea desde el árabe "maymún" (el animal gracioso de cola larga), o desde el latín "monnula" (amiguita), o desde ambos.

Si ambas palabras derivan de "muño", estamos ante un caso de **polisemia**, es decir, de significados ligeramente distintos de una misma palabra que ha ido evolucionando hacia usos distintos. Si, en cambio, derivan de palabras distintas ("muño" y "mona"), estamos ante un caso de **homonimia**.